# How should a SQL script detect that it is executing on an AWS RDS SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, amazon-rds

I have some database deployment scripts that need to target on-premises and AWS RDS SQL Server instances, but some of the scripts execute commands that are not supported on RDS.

Rather than maintain two scripts (which would be 90% identical), I'd like to use procedural T-SQL logic to skip/modify sections of the script when it's running in RDS.

At the moment, I'm using the following logic

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'rdsadmin' AND database_id = 5)
...
```

Is there a better/more reliable way to determine that a script is executing on an RDS SQL Server instance?

(I might just be missing the right search terms to find the answer - apologies if so.)

Comment: This is the logic Ola Hallengren uses in his maintenance solution script: `DECLARE @AmazonRDS bit = CASE WHEN DB_ID('rdsadmin') IS NOT NULL AND SUSER_SNAME(0x01) = 'rdsa' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Answer (score 1):

At the present time, it appears that there is no single definitive indicator accessible from T-SQL that indicates an instance is running in AWS RDS.

Instead, there are a number of settings/objects that indicate that an instance is *probably* running on RDS, including (but not limited to):

- The presence of an `rdsadmin` database (with DBID 5)
- `SUSER_SNAME(0x01) = 'rdsa'`
- The presence of stored procedures in `msdb` with names starting `rds_` - for example, `msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database`

If any two of these tests is true, it's likely that the instance is running in RDS.